# Merge (1 with 2, 3 with 4, etc.) elements of array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]`

I want to merge elements like this  `[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10,11,12]]`. But have no idea how...

Comment: you could use just the result. it's fine. where is the problem with it?

Comment: You can get some inspiration if you read the documentation of JavaScript [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Hmmm, maybe try Array.prototype.concat?

Comment: Are you basing this on any criteria, like numbers less than 7 go in the first array, all others in the second. Or, each array must only have 6 numbers. What if you have another array that has `[1, 12, 9]`, what happens then? Your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following (works only with even number of elements)

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]];

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  result.push(arr[i].concat(arr[i+1]));
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array and use the index with bitshifting for the right new index of the result array.

```js
var array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]],
    combined = array.reduce((r, a, i) =>
        Object.assign(r, { [i >> 1]: [...(r[i >> 1] || []), ...a] }), []);
    
console.log(combined);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution that merges any number of consequent arrays:

```js
let range = n => [...Array(n).keys()];

let chunks = (a, n) => range(Math.ceil(a.length / n))
    .map(i => a.slice(i * n, (i + 1) * n));

let mergeEvery = (a, n) => chunks(a, n).map(g => [].concat(...g));

a = [[1,2,3], [4], [5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14], [15]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(mergeEvery(a, 2)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(mergeEvery(a, 3)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(mergeEvery(a, 4)))
```